# I need a solution for uploading a photo and also i want to view all the uploaded photo ? in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload photos and also i want to view all the uploaded photos. like a photo album

Comment: What is your question?  This forum is for answering questions not get others to build applications for you.  Give it a shot and when you get stuck come back with a specific question.

Comment: If you have no idea about where to start, you could search for `photo album in asp.net` in Google.

Comment: or may be you could search for `photo gallery in ASP.Net`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Jquery.  Given below is the upload image code snippet. Once you are done with it, then i leave it to you to design the photo album like structure... Happy coding....

Two steps
1. Upload & crop if required
2. Show the uploaded one

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UploadCropShow.aspx.cs" Inherits="UploadCropShow" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>UploadCropShow</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="frmImage" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlUpload" runat="server">
      <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" />
      <br />
      <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload" />
      <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCrop" runat="server" Visible="false">
      <asp:Image ID="cropImage" runat="server" />
      <br />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="Hori" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="Verti" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="Width" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="Height" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnCrop" runat="server" Text="Crop" OnClick="btnCrop_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCropped" runat="server" Visible="false">
      <asp:Image ID="imgCropped" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you will need to use Jquery and jcrop.js.  So link them under  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.Jcrop.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: I have not used styles here.  Use them as required

write this script tag as well as a part of your html page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#cropImage').Jcrop({
      onSelect: performAction
    });
  });

  function performAction(c) {
    jQuery('#Hori').val(c.x);
    jQuery('#Verti').val(c.y);
    jQuery('#Width').val(c.w);
    jQuery('#Height').val(c.h);
  };
</script>
```

From your aspx file, use this for upload
Note: I have not checked for valid image file n all.  Just the happy path logic

```
public void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isFileSaved = false;
    string path = "C:\\Images\\..."; // Specify save path here...
    try
    {
      Upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
      isFileSaved = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      lblError.Text = "File could not be uploaded." + ex.ToString();
      lblError.Visible = true;
    }

  if (isFileSaved)
  {
    pnlUpload.Visible = false;
    pnlCrop.Visible = true;
    cropImage.ImageUrl = path;
  }
}
```

Event for Crop

```
public void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int _width = Convert.ToInt32(Width.Value);
  int _height = Convert.ToInt32(Height.Value);
  int _hori = Convert.ToInt32(Hori.Value);
  int _verti = Convert.ToInt32(Verti.Value);
  string ImageName = path;

  byte[] ImageToCrop = ReSize(path + ImageName, _width, _height, _hori, _verti);
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImageToCrop, 0, ImageToCrop.Length))
  {
    ms.Write(ImageToCrop, 0, ImageToCrop.Length);
    using(SD.Image CroppedImage = SD.Image.FromStream(ms, true))
    {
      string saveTo = path + "crop" + ImageName;
      CroppedImage.Save(SaveTo, CroppedImage.RawFormat);
      pnlCrop.Visible = false;
      pnlCropped.Visible = true;
      imgCropped.ImageUrl = "cropped image url" + ImageName;
    }
  }
}
```

you could have noticed ReSize method call which is this.

```
static byte[] ReSize(string Img, int Width, int Height, int Hori, int Verti)
{
  try
  {
    using (SD.Image OriginalImage = SD.Image.FromFile(Img))
    {
      using (SD.Bitmap bmp = new SD.Bitmap(Width, Height))
      {
        bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution,  OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);
        using (SD.Graphics Graphic = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
          Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
          Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
          Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
          Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), Hori, Verti, Width, Height, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
          bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);
          return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Handle ex here
  }
}
```